# Is an anchor in nested list invalid or is this a firebug error?

Tags: html, firebug

Is there something wrong with the following HTML, or am I simply experiencing a Firebug error? When I view the first list element in firebug, you'll see that firebug has difficulty correctly identifying the anchor; however, it has no problem with the second (outer) list element. If I remove the nested list from the first list element, then the problem disappears. Similarly, if I remove the outer list, the problem disappears. So, there appears to be a problem with placing an anchor around a nested list.

I've tried replacing the anchor with a div, and even a span, and firebug doesn't complain, so this seems to be anchor specific. I've also tried various doctypes, with no success.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="http://whatever" style="display:block">
          <p>some text</p>
          <ul>
            <li>a list entry</li>
          </ul>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="http://whatever">
           <p>more text</p>
        </a>
       </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a` element only allows [inline-level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#inline) as child elements. So the `p` element and `ul` element are not allowed there.

Comment: I wondered whether this was the problem. If it is, then there are some inconsistencies (why is there no problem if I replace the anchor with a span? And why is there still a problem if I wrap the contents in a div with its display set to inline?)

Comment: @darasd a span is an inline element, so is a div set to display:inline.

Comment: @Bart exactly. in the first case (replace anchor with span), I have an inline element containing block elements, but there is no problem. In the second place (wrap contents of anchor with inline div), I have an anchor containing an inline element, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Also, this doesn't explain why the problem disappears if I remove the outer (parent) list.